# Did a Yu-Gi-Oh tournament prize card sell for $2 million USD?

Tags: japan, games, price

I recently learned about a prize given out for the first ever Yu-gi-oh tournament in Japan in 1999, a stainless steel normal monster Black Luster Soldier.  In numerous online english-language articles, the card is cited as being sold for $2 million in 2013.  Here are just a few of the many examples: [1](https://rarest.org/entertainment/yu-gi-oh-cards) [[2]](https://giftsforcardplayers.com/yu-gi-oh-exploring-steel-card/) [[3]](https://www.one37pm.com/grind/money/most-expensive-trading-card) [[4]](https://www.theverge.com/2018/1/20/16909756/blue-eyes-ultimate-dragon-rare-yu-gi-oh-card-tokyo-sale) [[5 (linked to by 4)]](https://web.archive.org/web/20180120231558/https://gemr.com/blog/the-10-most-expensive-yu-gi-oh-cards/).  (If you google search for the card, you will find 15+ more articles mentioning the card.)
Without exception, the articles claim that the card was listed for the USD equivalent of $10 million, and "rumored" or "reported" to have been sold for $2 million.  Most of the articles cite no source for the rumor or reported claim, and the few that do just cite other articles with the same claim.

Example from link 3 above: "It is rumored that it has been bought for $2 million."

The "listed for $10 million" claim appears to be legitimate, as I found a [contemporary english-language article](https://kotaku.com/someone-wants-10-million-for-this-yu-gi-oh-card-1226135508) mentioning the asking price.  But my attempts to find the source of this $2 million sale price claim have come up short.  Can anyone find a source, in any language, that either validates/refutes the claim, or that appears to be a likely origin of the claim on the internet?

[image: BLS picture]

Comment: Important to point out - this is less of a card and more of a collectible, as it can't be used in actual play. It is a display piece, not unlike a trophy - nothing more.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**No Japanese source for this**

This is a one-of-a-kind card and there is no information in Japanese about its sale or current ownership. At one point a Yahoo Auctions listing was created with a $10 million (actually 998 million yen) price tag, but this was clearly not meant for sale but as a form of bragging. [According to a Yugioh website](https://yugioh-resaler.com/2019/07/15/taikai-yusho-card/) there is no public information on any actual sale of the card, and I do not see it discussed elsewhere. Apparently this card has been discussed a few times on the Q&A website Chiebukuro but I saw no record of a $2 million sale, or any kind of sale, in Japanese sources.

**Record price is $427,000**

As mentioned in one of your sources the highest recorded price for a Yugioh card is 45 million yen ($427k) for a four-of-a-kind award variant of the famous Ultimate Blue-Eyes White Dragon. This price was posted publicly at a trading card shop in Akihabara. It was reportedly sold to the YouTuber Yukkichi, who works with the content agency [UUUM](https://en.uuum.co.jp/), so I think is much more verifiable information. This is the top price mentioned by Japanese websites.